# Setting up SSH Server in WSL 2

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to setup ssh server on my WSL 2 for local development. I can connect to it from Putty but having trouble connecting from another machine in the same local network. I try to follow scripts from [WSL GitHub Issue #4150](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-628217589) but I might not be able to modify the script well enough to make it work for the use case. I'm getting a connection timed out message error.

Thank you in advance.